# Possible to reorder solution folders?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2013 I'm using [Solution Folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haytww03%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to organize and group the projects of my solution.

The solution folders are always ordered alphabetically, e.g.

```
+ My Solution
    + Solution Folder 1
    + Solution Folder 2
```

What I'm looking for is a way to change the order position of the solutions folders, e.g.:

```
+ My Solution
    + Solution Folder 2
    + Solution Folder 1
```

Currently I found no way (and no external tool) to change the order position manually. (Beside renaming it or prefixing the names, of course)

**My question:**

Is there a way or 3rd party tool that lets me manually specify the order position of solution folders in Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Not that I know of. I put a number in front of the name to order them.